# Best way to deal with copy-vio in tag wiki, when copy-vio is only content(no prior revisions)

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I realize this has been asked before, although in differing circumstances, such as mass amounts of bad edits.  However, in this case(I'm not sure from my research if this has occurred before), the copy-vio is the only revision present on the tag wiki.

I'm not that good of a writer, so I'd either be blanking the page(which might be considered vandalism by some), or leaving it for someone else to fix.

How to deal with the above, where the copyright violation is the only revision present on the tag wiki, and where the viewer is not that good of a writer so as to fix it so it is not?

If any are curious, the tag wiki referenced by this question is: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ionic/info

Comment: How did such an obvious blurb from a product's website make it into a tag wiki? Oh wait, [robo reviewers!](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6473020)

Comment: I'm of the opinion, kinda, that this doesn't really matter. If I had a product that someone asked questions about on StackOverflow, and someone copied my promotional material and put it in the tag wiki, that just saves me the trouble.  That's the information I want to put out about my she-it, so having that in a tag referencing my she-it is a *good thing*.  No harm, no foul.

Comment: I agree with Will, it doesn't really harm the company that owns the product. However, it does lower the quality of StackOverflow. So I've just edited it a little bit to take out the most egregious marketing language (my edit is currently in the edit queue). I would do more, but I don't have much time right now. This tag wiki still needs a lot more work.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk It is in the queue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8648078)